# IcoMoon in iOS project

Tags: ios, font-awesome

I succeeded in loading FontAwesome in my iOS project but I was wondering if it is possible to load IcoMoon Icon Font too.

Comment: iOS project meaning iOS Application or an HTML5 App?

Comment: If you can load FontAwesome into your project, I see no difference in loading IcoMoon, they are the same. Good luck! :)

Comment: Have you experimented it? I'm having problems with Icomoon and I'm doing the same way as FontAwesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few more testing IcoMoon is working now. The problem was related to my Info.plist file. I have deleted and recreated it and the font is now installed.